# Flutter iOS display name localization is not functioning correctly, but only for the zh-Hans locale

Tags: ios, flutter, localization

I encountered a peculiar issue when I was implementing Display Name localization for my iOS app developed using Flutter. Everything was working as expected on all locales except for Simplified Chinese (zh-Hans). When I switched to zh-Hans on my devices or simulator, the name displayed under the app icon defaulted to `Runner`, which is the default Flutter name.

What's even more puzzling is that only the display names on the Home and Settings screens show as `Runner`. I attempted to retrieve the display name within the app using Dart, and it returned the exact string I set. Even the deletion confirmation dialog displayed the correct name!

[image]

Following is the `InfoPlist.xcstrings` content:

```json
{
  "sourceLanguage" : "en",
  "strings" : {
    "CFBundleDisplayName" : {
      "comment" : "Display name",
      "extractionState" : "manual",
      "localizations" : {
        "en" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "xBangon"
          }
        },
        "zh-Hans" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "瓦工帮"
          }
        },
        "zh-Hant" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "瓦工幫"
          }
        },
        "zh-HK" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "瓦工帮"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "CFBundleName" : {
      "comment" : "Bundle name",
      "extractionState" : "extracted_with_value",
      "localizations" : {
        "en" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "new",
            "value" : "xBangon"
          }
        },
        "zh-Hans" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "瓦工帮"
          }
        },
        "zh-Hant" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "瓦工幫"
          }
        },
        "zh-HK" : {
          "stringUnit" : {
            "state" : "translated",
            "value" : "瓦工帮"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "version" : "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue. After changing the localization from `zh-CN` to `zh` in the `Info.plist` file, it now works with all languages.

[image]

Comment: I also faced the same problem as you, but that answer didn't solve it for me.
So I would like to know, on what basis did you base your answer? Did you refer to some article?

Comment: @sub No article was referenced; I just tried and it worked accidentally. Sorry for not being of assistance to you.

Comment: That's right!
That's outrageous. thank you.